# Is it true that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0 \implies \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = 0$?

Tags: calculus

Is it true that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0 \implies \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = 0$$ ?

Assume that  $f$ and $g$ admit derivatives $f'$ and $g'$ at every point in an open interval $I$ which contains zero; $g(x) > 0$ for every $x$ in $I$.

I am supposed to use Taylor Polynomials to discuss that. I think it doesn't hold. Does someone know a counterexample?

Comment: Let $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=1+x$.

Comment: Despite the counterexamples, it is true if you add the condition that f(x) and g(x) both tend to zero as x tends to zero... this result is called L'Hopital's Rule and would also work with the limits being values other than zero

Comment: @Assaultous2: No, L'Hospital is the opposite implication. Counterexample to your claim: $f(x)=x^2 \sin(1/x)$, $g(x)=x$.

Comment: @ Hans Lundmark: L'Hopital's rule assumes the limit exists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Counterexample:**

$$f(x) = 0$$
$$g(x) = 1 $$